# How to take screenshot of Current window or simulate print screen using selenium web drivver

Tags: java, selenium

I am creating an automation tool , which will help in taking screen shot of the web page , I m using Selenium Web driver (Java) , Currently I m able to take screen shot of the entire web page with the following code

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("full.jpeg"));
```

But I want to take screen shot of the current  window  alone (I want to simulate the action of print screen function) using selenium , kindly guide me , on how to take screen-shot of the current web page alone .Thanks in Advance

Regards,
Vignesh

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at my utility code

```
public static String captureScreen() {
    //get your driver instance        
    try {
        File source = ((TakesScreenshot)
                driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy/MMM/dd HH:mm:ss");
        String dateN = formatter.format(currentDate.getTime()).replace("/","_");
        String dateNow = dateN.replace(":","_");
        String snapShotDirectory =  /*your snapshot folder path*/+ dateNow;

        File f = new File(snapShotDirectory);
        if(f.mkdir()){
        path = f.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + source.getName();
        FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(path)); 
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        path = "Failed to capture screenshot: " + e.getMessage();
    }
    return path; 
}
```

just call this method wherever you want to take snapshots.

Comment: The following code takes the screenshot of the entire webpage , if the page has some 10 pages then it will take snapshot of all the 10 pages , but i want to take screenshot of only one page I want to simulate the action of printscreen alone , and i dont want to use robot class ,as i want to take the screenshot in the background

Comment: This code takes snapshot of only the frame or webpage to which webdriver is switched to using driver.switchTo().. It is tried and tested.. i dont know what you have done.. Can you explain ?

Comment: I m currently working on publishing website , and i want to take screenshot of the current window only , the website does not have pop ups and other frames , i would like to take screenshot of the current window alone , , but rightnow i m getting the screenshot of the entire webpage ,

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in WebDriver that supports this, but you can take a screenshot using Java Robots:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29

Comment: No i want to capture the screenshot in the background , so i wont be able to use Java Robots class

Comment: What you are describing isn't possible...Chrome currently only takes a screenshot of the visible portions of the page, with black covering the rest, I believe...but other than that, I think your only option is to crop the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks dude , i tested the following code in chrome and it is working properly in chrome :) , i m able to get the visible portion of the page alone now ,  but unfortunately my application is compatible with firefox only , and is there any way to get the visible part of the browser alone in screenshot ,  when i run the same code using firefox driver i m getting the screenshot of the entire web page , which i dont want , and i cant use Java Robot class as i want to run the browser in the backend as well. Any suggestion will be of great help to me .Thanks in Advance :)

Comment: No.  The reason it works in Chrome is due to a bug, which they are planning on fixing.  I have no idea how to cause the bug on firefox.