# How to simulate Print screen button using selenium webdriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to simulate Print screen button using selenium web driver in Java

Regards,
Vignesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot using Selenium WebDriver with Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-using-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: Its actually a repeated question...he asked a clearer one earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047675/how-to-take-screenshot-of-current-window-or-simulate-print-screen-using-selenium

Comment: I tried the following code, WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com/");File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));                                                 But the problem with the code is it will take screenshot of the entire webpage , if say the webpage has 5 pages it will take screenshot of the all the 5 pages , but i want to take only the current page and i want to run this code in the backend hence i cant use Robot().createScreenCapture method as well

Comment: Maybe your question already has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`selenium` doesn't support it, only web page shots. However you can use `Robot` to do it

```
try {
    String format = "jpg";
    String fileName = printScreen." + format;

    Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage screenFullImage = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
    ImageIO.write(screenFullImage, format, new File(fileName));

} catch (AWTException | IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex);
}
```

And in C#

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
bitmap.Save(@"C:\ScreenShots\printScreen.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: how can we do this in c#

Comment: @TalibAllauddin Added solution.