# I want to capture a screenshot of an element with tooltip using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I want to capture the tooltip of Business menu using Selenium JAva..I used javascript and action class to mouse over, but failed to capture the tooltip... Below is my part of code..Any help is appreciated...

the web is "https://www.rediff.com/news"..Sel

```
By tooltip = By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[1]/ul/li[3]/a");
        String TP_realtime = driver.findElement(tooltip).getAttribute("title");
        System.out.println("Tooltip is " + TP_realtime );
        
        WebElement realtime = driver.findElement(tooltip);

        js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", realtime);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        action.moveToElement(realtime).build().perform();
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        utils.HelperFunctions.captureScreenShot(driver, filename2);
```

Comment: The only way I was ever able to capture menu/tooltips  is to have a delay( while you setup the scene)  and do a full screen capture.  Then you can crop the picture to what you want.  I did not try the code you are using.

Comment: @JeyanthiRanjit Were you able to make the tool tip visible before taking the screenshot?

Comment: Yes @DebanjanB.. I can capture it using prt SC and paste it in paint.. it shows tooltip text...

Comment: You can simulate PRT SC press with Robot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19048119/how-to-simulate-print-screen-button-using-selenium-webdriver-in-java